# Sending personalized bulk email using POP3/IMAP

Tags: email, gmail, bulk

I have a list of email addresses and names that I'd like to send a mass email to. I would like the email to look something like:

> From: me@gmail.com
>
> To: email@example.com
>
> Body: Hi [name], I'm contacting you because...

I've gotten emails like this before, but I've never known how to do it. What programs can I use to send an email like this? Preferably, I'd like to somehow use my gmail account.

Comment: As a side note: Are you in the US? If so, you might want to check out CAN SPAM and its requirements (like a physical address in the body, and a way to opt out...it is up to a $1000 fine per e-mail for violations). Also, be aware that your ISP could literally cut off your connection if you are spamming and they get complaints. You may be better off having a 3rd party do it for your. They will know the ins and outs of not getting you in hot water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail allows your to create ['groups'](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/create-personal-mailing-lists-through.html) of emails. You can then send an email to people within this group. To ensure that each recipient sees only their email address in the `To` field, add the group only to `Bcc` when sending the email. Also, put your own address in the `To` box as if this is left blank some receiving servers (not gmail addresses) will reveal the other addresses.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Any answer for personalising the [name]?