# Mailutils sending automatic personalized emails from my gmail account

Tags: email, script, automation, gmail, mailutils

I want to create a script (or use one if it exists) that will do the following:

1. Personalize the body of the text based on the name/email of the recipient (i.e., `Hello {name}, bla bla…`)
2. Programmatically send the message to a list of email addresses that is in a file like CSV.
3. Send thoses email from my Gmail account so that recipients can respond to my email and I can see the email thread in my Gmail mailbox.

I found and read the documentation for the [GNU Mailutils](https://mailutils.org/manual/) that is probably the tool to use, and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1431925/automate-mass-personalized-email-sending-from-spreadsheet) gives a starting point for the personalization aspect.

However, I don’t know how to put those two things together, and above all I don’t know how to send the emails from my Gmail account (i.e., step #3).

Ideas? Approaches? Scripts available?